# How to see jQuery generated HTML?

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML created by jQuery and appended to a div:

```
var element = "<div style='background-color:red' class='some'/>";
$("#result").append(element);
```

When I run this code and dispaly a source via Crtl + U, I can't see this piece. Is there a way to see full source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inspection in your browser, in Firefox for example, you can right-click any element and click "inspect element", that also opens the HTML inspector (Ctrl Shift C).

Showing source only shows the original source loaded from server, it doesn't reflect any client-side changes.